How to batch render with UI open for the blend files
i have a few blender files which use drivers in the video sequencer, the drivers only update when rendering from the UI, any script or batch render command which doesnt open the UI fails to update the drivers when rendering, anyway to open UI while batch rendering either from script or cmd?
